# how to create a factorial data frame in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, factors

How can I create a pandas data frame using all possible combinations of factors?

```
factor1 = ['a','b']
factor2 = ['x','y,'z']
factor3 = [1, 2]
val = 0
```

This is what I'm aiming for:

```
   factor1 factor2  factor3  val
      a       x        1      0
      a       y        1      0
      a       z        1      0
      a       x        2      0
      a       y        2      0
      a       z        2      0   
      b       x        1      0
      b       y        1      0
      b       z        1      0
      b       x        2      0
      b       y        2      0
      b       z        2      0
```

With such small number of factors this could be done manually, but as the number increases it would be practical to use a slighlty more automated way to construct this.

Comment: does the order matter to you?

Comment: @Justin L.: Not necessarily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what [list comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) are for.

```
factor1 = ['a','b']
factor2 = ['x','y,'z']
factor3 = [1, 2]
val = 0

combs = [ (f1, f2, f3, val)
    for f1 in factor2
    for f2 in factor2
    for f3 in factor3 ]
# [ ('a', 'x', 1, 0),
#   ('a', 'x', 2, 0),
#   ('a', 'y', 1, 0),
#   ('a', 'y', 2, 0),
#   ... etc
```

replace `(f1, f2, f3, val)` with whatever you want to use to print the table.  Or you can print it from the list of tuples.

mathematically this is known as the [Cartesian Product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product).

Answer (score 1):

Since I want a pandas data frame I actually created a list of dictionaries (in order to have column names):

```
import pandas as pd

combs = [ {'factor1':f1, 'factor2':f2, 'factor3':f3, 'val':val} for f1 in factor1 for f2 in factor2 for f3 in factor3 ]
df = pd.DataFrame(combs)
```